# Python - Threads inside Thread - kosher?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Trying to implement a generic class which will do remote command execution using Paramiko.

Faced with this question.

The **init**() method of the class which is inheriting threading.Thread will do the connect to the host and the run() method will do the command execution on the remote host.

Now the command which is getting executed is a daemon.

That daemon will be ready to accept inputs on the stdin and will be spewing out messages on the stdout and stderr.

How should we handle this stderr, stdout reading while putting stuff on stdin ? I was thinking of using 3 more threads to do regular checking on the stream handles and handling the I/O to the remote daemon in that way.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing here is use queues to ferry out the STDOUT/STDERR and ferry in STDIN to this thread class.

Worked wonderfully as expected.